# Strange behavior of while-loop condition

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch

I have the following method. I am experiencing a strange behavior with regards to the WHILE loop below.

I am initially setting the value of the boolean `notDone` to `true`. Inside the WHILE loop, *first time there is an exception* so the program control goes to the CATCH block. The *2nd time the call to execute() method is successful*. I also see the println statement (`getProperties() postExecute()`) with the correct value of `notDone` (gets correctly set to `false`). However **despite this the, while loop condition gets satisfied and the execute() method gets invoked again**. Any ideas as to what is causing the while condition to fail ?

```
    public List<Property> getProperties() {
        int count = 0;
        boolean notDone = true;
        while (notDone) {
            System.out.println("getProperties() notDone => " + notDone);
            try {
                execute();
                notDone = false;
                System.out.println("getProperties() postExecute() " + notDone);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("getProperties() Exception occured " + notDone);
                if (e instanceof java.net.UnknownHostException) {
                    // Potentially proxy error.
                    if (ConfigManager.getInstance().getConfig().isUseProxy()) {
                        System.out
                                .println("UnknownHostException - Switching off proxy");
                        ConfigManager.getInstance().getConfig()
                                .setUseProxy(false);
                    } else {
                        System.out
                                .println("UnknownHostException - Switching on proxy");
                        ConfigManager.getInstance().getConfig()
                                .setUseProxy(true);
                    }
                }

                if (count > 2) {
                    break;
                }

                count++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Please post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Code looks good. Note that with the test `if (count > 2) { break; }`, you have 3 potential loops before exiting.